# RestController with few classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a few classes in the JPA Base made with the use of SpringData and SpringBoot. I would like to create a controller which shows the rest  out of a few classes and not only one. Sadly, I can't find any examples.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user") 
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)//add
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUser(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: *which shows the rest out of a few classes and not only one*: what does that mean?

Comment: I have  classes: user: student and lecturer, and I would like to show a rest out of those two.

Comment: I'm very confused. You have already made a rest service that uses the `UserRepository`. You just need to create controllers for other `Class`es just like your example.